# A short story about a woman alone on a spaceship, she gives birth on the way to a planet, and is all alone

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Ι am looking for a short story about a woman alone on a spaceship, she gives birth on the way to a planet, and is all alone and the baby won't stop crying. It turns out to all be a simulation to get permission to breed.

I also remember later on she figures the baby was colicky and that's why it was crying, but in the meantime she was growing desperate with the crying so she puts on a spacesuit and goes to sit in the "outdoor hatch area" (like a landing or a lobby, I guess, leaving the baby safe inside) and, since there was no atmosphere there, no noise reaches her and she can relax a little bit.

It was in English, I found it online in a website offering short science fiction stories.

Comment: Do you have any more info to  give us? Like when did you read it, what language was it ?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)